# sorting in csv by first element in row

Tags: python, list, sorting, csv

i have a task where i must return a list containing values from a csv file. The first 2 values need to be used to calculate a special value, such that the list looks like [(special_value),row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6]]. The problem is that it must be sorted by the size of special_value, and after hours of trying i cannot seem to figure out a way to do it, each attempt just returns a list of the rows with the special_value calculated from each row, as found in the file. I have tried itemgetter(), and have been iterating through the rows using for loop. a sample of some code, which i know is clunky and messy.

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\filepath")
clean_1 = open("filename","r")
clean_1 = csv.reader(clean_1)



for row in clean_1:

    if len(row[0]) == 5:
        #code to find special_value
        special_value = str(special_value)
    if len(row[0]) == 6:
        #code to find special_value
        special_value = str(special_value)
    list = [[special_value],
             [row[2]],
             [row[3]],
             [row[4]],
             [row[5]],
             [row[6]]]


    print(list)
```

also tried with a tuple, different variable types ect.

Answer (score 0):

newlist = [special_value, row[1]... row[n]] - basically get all your fields into a list and keep appending new items to the list using newlist.append()

then print or store the below, if you want it to be sorted in reverse order, use reverse=True

`sorted(newlist, key = lambda x: x[0])`

Assuming 0 is the index where the special_value is placed